# Facet postfiletring in Solr (translating from ElasticSearch aggregation postfiltering)

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene, faceted-search

Let's say I have a structure like:

```
{"account_number":171,"balance":7091,
"firstname":"Nelda","lastname":"Hopper",
"age":39,"gender":"M",
"address":"742 Prospect Place","employer":"Equicom",
"email":"neldahopper@equicom.com",
"city":"Finderne","state":"SC"}
```

(the data comes from [here](https://github.com/bly2k/files/blob/master/accounts.zip?raw=true)).

If I write the following query in ElasticSearch:

```
POST /bank/_search?pretty
{
 "query":
  { "bool":
    { "must":
      [ { "range":
      { "balance": { "gte": 30000 } } } ] }   
  },
   "fields":["gender", "balance", "age"],

  "aggs":{
    "age_filter":{
      "filter":{
        "match":{
       "age":"30"
        }
      },
      "aggs":{
    "gender_stats":{
      "terms":{"field":"gender"}
    }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'll get (1) 402 query results for the main query and (2) aggregation on the 18 results that passed the filter "age:30".

I've tried to do the similar trick in Solr 5.1, but the closes I could get was this:

```
q=balance:[30000%20TO%20*]&facet=true&facet.field=gender&fq=age:30
```

with the big difference that the filter is now applied to the main query results, so I get only 18 results at all, and then apply a corresponding faceting.

Is there a way to write a Solr query that is entirely equivalent to the ElasticSearch one? I.e. getting full results and then applying filtering only to the aggregation/faceting?

NB: I've tried exclusion by tag:

```
q={!ex=tagForAge}balance:[30000%20TO%20*]&facet=true&facet.field=gender&fq={!tag="tagForAge"}age:30
```

but it does not seem to apply to the main query.

Answer (score 0):

Try appending `&facet.query=age:30` to your query.

This will basically generate your facets from a particular search query which in your case is `age:30`.

For more information check [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.query_:_Arbitrary_Query_Faceting).